# Deducing an incorrect statement when the mean and median are given

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, means, median

$~a,~b,~c,~d$ are positive integers such that $a~<~b~<~c~<~d$ If mean and median of $~a, ~b, ~c,~d$ are $35$ and $39$ respectively, then which one of the following statements cannot be true?

- a = 21
- a+c =71
- a+c=60
- d = 61

---

I after some attempts made it up to $b+c = 78$ and $a+d = 62$ but can't proceed further.

Moreover, please suggest a good title for this post.

Comment: Note that $a+c < a+d$ and $a+d = a+b+c+d - (b+c) = 140 - 78 = 62$. Thus $a+c$ cannot be $71$.

Comment: Note $a+b+c+d=35(4)=140$ and $a + c \lt b + d$. Thus, what can you conclude if $a + c = 71$?

Comment: @JohnOmielan a+c = 71 isn't possible right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Otherwise, we have $b + d \gt a + c = 71$ which means $(a + c) + (b + d) \gt 71 + 71 = 142$, contradicting that $a + b + c + d = 140$, as I stated earlier. Note the statement about the median's value has no particular effect on this problem.

Comment: If you understand the solution, please consider answering your own question. Also, in that case, feel free to basically use what I wrote in my comment above, although some form of attribution would then be appropriate. Finally, regarding your request to "please suggest a good tile for this post", one possibility is something like "Deducing an incorrect statement when the mean and median are given", or even since the problem statement and possibilities are relatively short, include everything within the title instead (although it would make it somewhat long then).

Answer (score 1):

With great help of @John Omielan's and @Gabriel Romon's comment, here is what I figured out:
Since $c < d \implies a+c < a+d$

and since $a+d = 62 \implies a+c<62 \implies a+c \neq 72$